# PHP Image faster fit to size

Tags: php, image-processing

Im trying to size images up(down) to a specified square 1736x1736 to fill, and it's taking about 2-3 seconds to process. I feel like there's a more efficient way than what I'm doing.

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imagepath);
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($width > $height) {
    $bigside = $width;
    } else {
    $bigside = $height;
    }
$oldimage = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath);
$newimage = imagecreatetruecolor($bigside, $bigside);
$preresize = imagecopy($newimage, $oldimage, ($bigside-$width)/2, ($bigside-$height)/2, 0, 0, $width, $height);
$fullsize = imagecreatetruecolor(1736, 1736);
$resized = imagecopyresampled($fullsize,$newimage,0,0,0,0,1736,1736,$bigside,$bigside);
$filepath = 'img/009/'.$subsubdir.'/'.$file_shot.'r.jpg';
imagejpeg($fullsize, $filepath);
```